# Active Learning Regression Problems

Tags: regression, active-learning

I Want to apply active learning in regression problems, but all the frameworks that I found are only for classification problems. Does someone know some framework for active learning in regression problems or maybe know how to compute some strategy, for example uncertainty sampling?

Comment: Which Frameworks did you find? https://modal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/examples/active_regression.html?highlight=Regression#Active-regression looks promising and supports regression